# Is this common way to build this class and method?

Tags: c#

I am a new developer therefore I have many questions:

In this class I get file path on the disk (wireshark file that needs to be converted to pcap format extension) and convert it with the method `convertFileToPcap()`, in the constructor I am calling `convertFileToPcap()` and from the main after create the Editcap object I am receiving the new file path (pcap format) with the property `getNewFileName()` who return `_newFileName` (class member) and I want to know if there is a better way or appropriate way to do it.

```
public class Editcap
{
    #region members
    private string _editpcap;
    private ProcessStartInfo _editpcapProcess;
    private FileInfo _fileInfo;
    private string _newFileName;
    #endregion

    #region c'tor
    public Editcap(FileInfo fileinfo)
    {
        _fileInfo = fileinfo;
        _newFileName = "";
        convertFileToPcap();
    }
    #endregion

    public void convertFileToPcap()
    {
        string oldFileExtension = _fileInfo.Extension;
        _newFileName = _fileInfo.FullName.Replace(oldFileExtension, "_new") + ".pcap";
        _editpcapProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(string.Format("\"{0}\"", _editpcap));
        _editpcapProcess.Arguments = (string.Format("{2}{0}{2} -F libpcap {2}{1}{2}", _fileInfo.FullName, _newFileName, "\""));
        _editpcapProcess.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        _editpcapProcess.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        _editpcapProcess.RedirectStandardError = true;
        _editpcapProcess.CreateNoWindow = true;
        _editpcapProcess.UseShellExecute = false;
        _editpcapProcess.ErrorDialog = false;
        Process capinfosProcess = Process.Start(_editpcapProcess);
        capinfosProcess.WaitForExit();
    }

    public string getNewFileName()
    {
        return _newFileName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Hello and welcome to Code Review!

- I'd like to first direct you to Microsoft's official [naming
  guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0.aspx) for C# development. Your code goes against a few of
  those, and if that's your company's or team's guidelines, than great!
  If you don't have an official style, start with the ones I linked to.
- I'd definitely **not** call the convert method from the constructor.
  This could throw exceptions that would prevent the object from being
  created. Keep your processing methods separate and let the caller
  call it. It IS `public`, after all!
- your member variables seem a little too, well, global, in some cases.
  Only `_fileInfo` and `_newFileName` are used in more than one method.
  Keep the others local to their methods.

  - As part of this, note that `_editpcap` never gets assigned and is
    always `null`. I don't think that's what you're intending.
- the `getNewFileName` method looks very Java-like as Java didn't have
  the concept of properties. This is a prime candidate for being made a
  property.
- the `Process` class is `IDisposable`, so wrapping it in a `using`
  block is idiomatic.
- now I'm just getting into minor nitpicking, the fields set in the
  constructor are invariant after construction, so make the intent
  known by using the `readonly` keyword. Also, you can employ modern C#
  amenities as object initializers and the `var` keyword.

All this being said, here is my proposed refactor of the code:

```
public class Editcap
{
    #region members
    private readonly FileInfo fileInfo;
    private string newFileName = string.Empty;
    #endregion

    #region c'tor
    public Editcap(FileInfo fileinfo)
    {
        if (fileinfo == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fileInfo");
        }

        this.fileInfo = fileinfo;
    }
    #endregion

    public void ConvertFileToPcap()
    {
        this.newFileName = this.fileInfo.FullName.Replace(this.fileInfo.Extension, "_new") + ".pcap";

        string editpcap = null; // still not set, need to fix!
        var editpcapProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(string.Format("\"{0}\"", editpcap))
        {
            Arguments = string.Format("{2}{0}{2} -F libpcap {2}{1}{2}", this.fileInfo.FullName, this.newFileName, "\""),
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            ErrorDialog = false
        };

        using (var capinfosProcess = Process.Start(editpcapProcess))
        {
            capinfosProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }

    public string NewFileName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.newFileName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely cleaner, but regions are considered ugly by some plus I do not see any need for saving the state, so a class is only useful as a namespace (and C# does not allow having functions outside of a class). So, I would have no constructor but a single public static method that takes `FileInfo` and returns a string. That way you get a nice black box. The implementation can be split up amongst several `private static` methods.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't address the `region` thing as I have experience inheriting a large codebase from 2003 following the recommended usage then. One hell of a cleanup effort.